# Как перенести подвал в правый угол CSS

Tags: html, css

Как перенести подвал в правый угол

```
        #footer {
        position: fixed; 
        left: 0;  bottom: 0; 
        padding: 10px; 
        background: #39b54a; 
        color: #fff; 
        width: 100%; 
    }
```

Так надпись находится в левом угле странице. Замена на право не помогает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотря что Вам нужно. Если нужно, чтобы текст был справа, тогда:

```
text-align:right;
```

Если нужно, чтобы любой контент был справа, можно сделать так:

1. обернуть внутренность подвала в `div`;
2. задать ему `float: right;`. [Вот jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLa51bs1/1/)

Comment: Большое спасибо помогло!

Comment: @Павел если ответ вас устравивает - примите его (отметьте зеленой галочкой по рейтингом сообщения)

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно выровнять текст, то так:

```
 text-align:right;
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/shilgen/x0p8a9n5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

При замене `left: 0;` на `right: 0;` ничего не происходит, потому, что следующим, стоит свойство `width: 100%;` То есть фактически элемент который надо выровнять, уже выровнен по левой и правой стороне, растянувшись на всю ширину родительского элемента. Для того чтобы выровнять блок по правой стороне (именно блок, а не текст), нужно изменить значение width на меньшее чем 100% и поменять свойство-значение с `left: 0;` на `right: 0;` Если же надо выровнять только текст удобнее всего будет использовать свойство `text-align: right;`